# Laravel - return time ago like "2d ago"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is the best way to convert PHP date to format like this:

```
3d ago
18h ago
```

Having to implement this functionality for each project can be tiresome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time ago function php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397114/time-ago-function-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing I was able to come with was this model method:

```
public function getTimeAgo($carbonObject) {
    return str_ireplace(
        [' seconds', ' second', ' minutes', ' minute', ' hours', ' hour', ' days', ' day', ' weeks', ' week'], 
        ['s', 's', 'm', 'm', 'h', 'h', 'd', 'd', 'w', 'w'], 
        $carbonObject->diffForHumans()
    );
}
```

**Use it like:**

```
$message->getTimeAgo($message->created_at);
```

**Example output:**

- `2d ago`
- `3w ago`

---

*Notice:* `Carbon->diffForHumans()` actually returns `3 days ago` and `18 hours ago` so I needed to use `str_ireplace` function